# How to convert boolean to string - NestJS / JS / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, automapper, mapper

I am new to NestJS as a server.
I have a table in DB that I am querying, and the column name is precedence, and it is boolean meaning in DB just 0 or 1.
I have this code that I understood maps the data to DTO.

```
forMember(
          (destination) => destination.precedence,
          mapFrom((source) => source.precedence),
        ),
```

but instead of 1 I need it to be true
and instead of 0 I need it to be false

Can it be done? in the mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to check if `source.precedence` is equal to '1' then return `true` else return `false`

```
forMember(
 (destination) => destination.precedence,
 mapFrom((source) => source.precedence === 1), // this will return false also if the value is different from 0 and 1
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a falsy or truthy value to a boolean with a double negation

```js
console.log(!!0)
console.log(!!1)
// and just convert your boolean to string if you need to
console.log((!!0).toString())
console.log((!!1).toString())
```